# unix shell script to search all files within sub directories(more than one) in a directory

Tags: shell, unix

I want to extract common data from all the files within multiple sub directories of a directory?
Please suggest me a script to do it.

Comment: Use `grep -R`. The option `-R` stands for recursive.

Comment: You want to search only files which are in a subdirectory of a subdirectory? Or does "more than one" simply mean there are multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

use `grep -Hr "search pattern" /path/dir`